# Twitter bootstrap : Cannot disable the tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

**What I'm trying to do?**

Below is my script for using Twitter Bootstrap wizard, I want to disable certain tab(s) on button click

**What is the problem?**

When I click the button I get the below error

> Index:2138 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).bootstrapWizard is not a
>   function
>       at HTMLInputElement. (Index:2138)
>       at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (VM292 jquery-1.10.2.js:5109)
>       at HTMLInputElement.elemData.handle (VM292 jquery-1.10.2.js:4780)

Note: The line numbers are not valid

What's strange is that the error occurs only on the line where I'm disabling the tab `$('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard("disable", 4);`But there is one more line where I have used the function bootstrapWizard, but that works just fine `$('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard({`

I thought it was due to the sequence in which I have included the .js scripts, so I tried changing the sequence, but that did not help.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks for your time.

```
@model Models.***

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <div id="rootwizard">
            <div class="navbar">
                <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs pager nav-tabs-justified" role="tablist" id="myTab">
                        <li class="active nav-item"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">0</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">1</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">2</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">3</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#tab5" data-toggle="tab">4</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#tab6" data-toggle="tab">5</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#tab7" data-toggle="tab">6</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#tab8" data-toggle="tab">7</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#tab9" data-toggle="tab">8</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#tab10" data-toggle="tab">9</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="bar" class="progress progress-striped">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;"></div>
            </div>

            @*Previous and Next buttons*@
            <ul class="pager wizard">
                @*<li class="previous first" style="display:none;"><a href="#">First</a></li>*@
                <li class="previous"><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
                @*<li class="next last" style="display:none;"><a href="#">Last</a></li>*@
                <li class="next"><a href="#">Next</a></li>
            </ul>

            <hr />

            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1">
                    <input type='button' class='btn' id='disable-step' value='Disable' />                        
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2">

                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3">

                </div>

                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab4">

                </div>

                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab5">

                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab6">

                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab7">

                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab8">

                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab9">

                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab10">

                </div>               

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
}
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.bootstrap.wizard.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        // This works fine
        $('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard({ 

            // disable the clicking on individual tabs so that users are forced to advance only using navigational buttons
            onTabClick: function (tab, navigation, index) {
                return false;
            },

            // adjust the progress-bar
            onTabShow: function (tab, navigation, index) {
                var $total = navigation.find('li').length;
                var $current = index + 1;
                var $percent = ($current / $total) * 100;
                $('#rootwizard .progress-bar').css({ width: $percent + '%' });
            },

            onNext: function (tab, navigation, index) {

                // validate input         

                return true;
            }

        });
    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Disable step
        $('#disable-step').on('click', function () {
            $('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard("disable", 4); // gives error
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Replace your `script` tags with this: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap-wizard/1.2/jquery.bootstrap.wizard.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`. Does it change the outcome?

Comment: Sorry, that did not change the outcome.